# How to check for dependencies for a specific page and enqueue them

Tags: ajax, wp-dependencies

I am creating a one page site where the content of the sections (separate pages) above and under the actual page section are lazy loaded via AJAX. Say in one of the pages a shortcode for a gallery plugin is used and the plugin only enqueues its dependencies on pages where the shortcode is used:

**How can I check which dependencies would be enqueued if a specific page is loaded?**

By 'page' I do not only mean actual pages or custom post types, but all sites WordPress generates, e.g. archive pages or the home page.

Comment: For shortcodes, you could use has_shortcode function to check if the content has a shortcode. If it does you can then enqueue the script required for that shortcode.  The shortcode my be properly registered for that function to work. Codex -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode

Comment: Shortcode was just an example. I don't know which shortcode I have to look for as it could be any third-party plugin. The dependencies could also be enqueued by a custom field or similar. I am looking for something like simulating a request.